# How to return Json List of object from Controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

In my jquery I call the `$.ajax()` function and I don't have any issues with that. My problem lies within the success part, where I want to be able to do something like the following:

```
$.ajax('/Home/GetData/' + id, // request url
{
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "POST",
    succes: function (response) { // success callback function
        alert("OK");
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert("Dynamic content load failed.");
    }
});
```

and my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetData(int Id)
{
    var results = (from subCategory in _db.SubCategories
     where subCategory.CategoryId == Id
     select subCategory).ToList();

    return Json(new { Response = results } , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I've got error message always. How Can I get List of objects from my controller and handle one in View.

Comment: What error? `GET` or `POST`? Typo `succes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I solved my problem with this..

public ActionResult GetData(int Id)
    {
        var results = (from subCategory in _db.SubCategories
            where subCategory.CategoryId == Id
            select subCategory).ToList();

        var list = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results,
            Formatting.None,
            new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
            });

        return Content(list, "application/json");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Your GetData() method is POST and you are returning JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet it should not be write over there. You have to change in this

```
 return Json(new { Response = results } , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetData(int Id)
{
    var results = (from subCategory in _db.SubCategories
     where subCategory.CategoryId == Id
     select subCategory).ToList();

return Json(results);
}
```

Comment: Error request always

Comment: As you are saying Error request right? that means so you should have to change in your jquery code i think it seems me like you are not getting value of id in your controller right?